# mask image with other image and custom color

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to achieve something like this one
[image]

I already have these assets

[image]
[image]

I am using this code to mask the cover image but still, it doesn't take the color. so anyone can help me? I can do the required changes for the images if that necessary.

My code:

```
let mask = UIImageView(image: mask-img)
coverImage = UIImageView(image: cover-img)
coverImage.mask = mask
```

here is the result after using this code
[image]

Comment: May be problem with your mask image?

Comment: here are my images https://www.dropbox.com/sh/som82iukdf4r6jn/AACLS5acIFFerkn2x2EAoWqya?dl=0 its not the problem, the problem that it read the alpha and show image depending on alpha regarding on the color

Comment: can you show your project? It is strange, I think you add some transformations or set not correct frames with a not correct value of property contentMode.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov i edited the description to add more details

Comment: The mask (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622557-mask) is only for the alpha channel. All color values are ignored. You should apply your mask image twice: Use it as mask as in your code and create an semi transparent additional image view which is on top of your image view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can achieve this in few ways, the most simple - use CoreGraphics.

First off all, you can check [this user guide provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html).

After, to add mask to image you can use something like

```
func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:UIImage) -> UIImage? {

        if let imageReference = image.cgImage,
            let maskReference = mask.cgImage,
            let dataProvider = maskReference.dataProvider {

            if let imageMask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskReference.width,
                                       height: maskReference.height,
                                       bitsPerComponent: maskReference.bitsPerComponent,
                                       bitsPerPixel: maskReference.bitsPerPixel,
                                       bytesPerRow: maskReference.bytesPerRow,
                                       provider: dataProvider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true) {

                if let maskedReference = imageReference.masking(imageMask) {
                    let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage: maskedReference)
                    return maskedImage
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

For test purpose I prepared simple playground with this. Available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GU18BxUf8hV2gxZk1QaHczMDg/view?usp=sharing).

Result:

[image]

And to achieve colored mask, you can apply tint effect to your masked image for example using:

```
private func tinted(_ image:UIImage, with color:UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    let rect:CGRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: image.size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, image.scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    image.draw(in: rect)
    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context.setBlendMode(.sourceAtop)
    context.fill(rect)
    if let result:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
    return nil
}
```

Demo:

[image]

And updated playground [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GU18BxUf8hZ0ZidkxLZW9lTWs/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Many thanks for your help, you saved my day. I'll award you the bounty